# Нужно ли двоеточие или тире

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите в предложении:
"По летописи дважды исключение есть правило",
нужно ли двоеточие или тире после слова "летописи".
Вроде исходя их правил употребления данных знаков - не надо (но, мне кажется, очень просится сюда что-то подобное), либо я правила не так читаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Вроде исходя их правил употребления
> данных знаков - не надо (но, мне
> кажется, очень просится сюда что-то
> подобное), либо я правила не так
> читаю.

Правило-то найти можно... См. http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=121#pp121 :

> **§ 76.** Обстоятельства, выраженные существительными, могут выделяться
> тире, если имеется потребность в
> особом подчеркивании таких
> обстоятельств…

А вот понять, что такое *"дважды исключение есть правило"...* (?)

Comment: Слава, а вы считаете, что ''по летописи'' - это обстоятельство?

Comment: А Вы считаете по-иному?

Comment: по чему - по летописи, а не КАК. Иначе получится, что исключение осуществляется при помощи летописи.

Comment: Нет, не "ПРИ ПОМОЩИ летописи".  СОГЛАСНО летописи. === Вы же сами писали: "Если сама летопись гласит, т.е. согласно летописи..."=== И чем же, по-вашему, может являться это "согласно летописи", как не обстоятельством, в синонимичном рассматриваемому предложении: "Согласно летописи(,) дважды исключение есть правило" ???=== А уж какой знак выбрать после "по летописи" -- запятую или тире...
Я бы выбрал тире, и правила это позволяют: см. выше.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы! Смысл предложения: в летописи написано, что дважды исключение есть правило (т.е. если исключение из правила повторится более одного раза, то оно само станет правилом). Ставлю тире.

Comment: Тире в таких предложениях не ставится! Цитирую тот же справочник: Обороты с производными предлогами и предложными сочетаниями обязательно обособляются, если они располагаются между подлежащим и сказуемым: разрыв их непосредственной связи и способствует выделению оборотов. В других позициях такие обороты могут не обособляться (без необходимости подчеркивания). Ср.: **Согласно приказу группа расформирована. — Группа, согласно приказу, расформирована**

Comment: Обстоятельства, выраженные существительными, могут выделяться тире, если имеется потребность в особом подчеркивании таких обстоятельств: При нашей последней встрече Олег попросил принести общую тетрадь с жесткими "корочками'' — для конспектирования лежа (газ.);

Comment: В нашем примере нет обстоятельства, выраженного существительным.

Comment: Серж : "Тире в таких предложениях НЕ СТАВИТСЯ! Цитирую тот же справочник…"===
Ну так прочитайте повнимательнее то, что Вы сами и процитировали: "В других позициях такие обороты МОГУТ не обособляться (без необходимости подчеркивания)…"===
МОГУТ не обособляться (если отсутствует необходимость в их подчёркивании) -- это не то же самое, что НЕ СТАВИТСЯ !===

Серж : "В нашем примере нет обстоятельства, выраженного существительным."=== А к какой же части речи Вы относите слово ЛЕТОПИСЬ?

Answer (score 1):

После "по летописи" нужна запятая: это вводное словосочетание, указывающее на источник сообщения.
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122
(п. 5)

Answer (score 0):

Все зависит от смысла. Если это цитата из летописи, тогда нужно двоеточие и кавычки. Если сама летопись гласит, т.е. согласно летописи, тогда никаких дополнительных знаков препинания не нужно.

Comment: При нашей последней встрече Олег попросил принести общую тетрадь с жесткими "корочками'' — для конспектирования лежа( как? - лежа). **Обстоятельство образа действия**. В нашем примере есть предлог. А вы говорите об обстоятельствах, выраженных существительными. Тогда надо говорить об оборотах с производными предлогами. Хотя здесь нет таковых. И на какой вопрос отвечает здесь об-во? Какое это об-во?